# Stack Exchange site for website development

Tags: support, site-recommendation

On which Stack Exchange site should I post questions regarding website development?

I am creating my own website using HTML and JavaScript, and I need some assistance in the same.

Can I use [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @SunilKumar No, you can't. This site is *not* for development questions.

Comment: @gnat That long post you've linked to still omits a lot of candidate sites which may well apply, like superuser, unix, and webapps -- just to name a few.

Comment: @tchrist it is intended to list all sites related to software development (this question asks about development); if some site about development is missing, it is expected to be added to the list

Comment: @tchrist: [webapps.se] is _very_ much _not_ for web app development questions.

Answer (score 9):

No. You can't use Programmers. That site is more about whiteboard questions, not for coding issues.

Stack Overflow on the other hand is the site to ask such questions. You need to work on the quality of your question since they don't like code dumps without sensible problem statement or error message.

Comment: The asker may well not know what "whiteboard questions" means. They might not have programming questions at all, just questions related to system or site configuration and operations.